# How to nest children components into parent and export them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

The goal is to nest components and export theme while keeping the base as the default component.

Here's the result I want to produce.

```
import Panel from './Panel';
...

<Panel> // important as it contains its own CSS.
    <Panel.Head>
        <h2>Some Header Text</h2>
    </Panel.Head>

    <Panel.Body>
        <p>Some Content...</p>
    </Panel.Body>

    <Panel.Footer>
        <button>Confirm action...</button>
    </Panel.Footer>
</Panel>
```

I can't find a way to nest Head, Body, Footer into the parent Panel with JS exports.

This is what I have so far.

```
const Head = (props) => (
    <div className="panel--head">{props.children}</div>
);

const Body = (props) => (
    <div className="panel--body">{props.children}</div>
);

const Footer = (props) => (
    <div className="panel--footer">{props.children}</div>
);

const Panel = (props) => (
    <div className="panel">{props.children}</div>
);

export default Panel;
export { Head, Body, Footer };
```

What I tried will import into `import Panel, { Head, Body, Footer } from './Panel';` which I'm trying to avoid.

Is this even possible? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is impossible Since we can't render a `Component` that could have subComponents like `Component.SubComponentA`, a workaround here is using the **render props API** which will allow to export each component separately and the `Panel` component to serve needed sub-components so here is the approach:

```
const PanelRP = (props) => (
  <div className="panel">{props.children({ Head, Body, Footer })}</div>
);
```

And we render it like below:

```
<PanelRP>
  {({ Head, Body, Footer }) => (
    <>
      <Head>head</Head>
      <Body>body</Body>
      <Footer>footer</Footer>
    </>
  )}
</PanelRP>
```

could this api solve your problem ?